# Retrieve "most current" document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am fairly new to MongoDB and have a collection containing documents with fields `regionId`, `typeId`, and a `timestamp`, among other things.

Is there an efficient way to retrieve the "most current" document for `regionId` and `typeId` pairs based on the `timestamp`? That is, given a document with a `regionId` and a `typeId`, there will be exactly one result and it will not have a smaller `timestamp` than non-selected documents.

I've tried indexing this with `{ regionId: 1, typeId: 1, timestamp: -1 }` and using the following aggregate pipeline:

```
{ "$match" : { "regionId" : 1234 } },
{ "$sort" : { "regionId" : 1 , "typeId" : 1 , "timestamp" : -1 } },
{ "$group" : {
    "_id" : { "regionId" : "$regionId" , "typeId" : "$typeId" },
    "timestamp" : { "$first" : "$timestamp" },
    "otherStuff" : { "$first" : "$otherStuff" },
} }
```

I can't really tell if it's returning the correct information since it fails with this error:

```
Command 'aggregate' failed: exception: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in. (response: { "errmsg" : "exception: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", "code" : 16819, "ok" : 0.0 })
Type: MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException
```

Any tips on how to do this right?

Comment: Did you try passing `allowDiskUse: true` option to the aggregate method?

Comment: If the number of regions and types are small, but the number of overall documents is large, then why would the desired behavior need to expand onto disk? That's what made me think I was not implementing what I wanted correctly.

Comment: How many documents are there matching regionId 1234? Also, how many distinct typeID values? Lastly, what specific version of MongoDB and O/S are you using?

Answer (score 0):

#### What's the most efficient way to write this query

Your query doesn't need to do any aggregation (i.e. calculation of values or manipulation of the documents), so you should instead use a standard `find()` query with a limit.

Example in the `mongo` shell:

```
db.foo.find({"regionId":1234}).sort({"regionId":1,"typeId":1,"timestamp":-1 }).limit(1)
```

A suitable index matching your query and sort criteria would be:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({"regionId":1, "typeId":1 , "timestamp": -1})
```

If you've added this index and `explain()` the query in MongoDB 2.6, you should see output similar to:

```
db.foo.find({"regionId":1234}).sort({ "regionId" : 1 ,"typeId" : 1 ,"timestamp" : -1 }).limit(1).explain()
{
  "cursor": "BtreeCursor regionId_1_typeId_1_timestamp_-1",
  "isMultiKey": false,
  "n": 1,
  "nscannedObjects": 1,
  "nscanned": 1,
  "scanAndOrder": false,
  ...
}
```

The [explain output](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain-output-fields) above indicates that this is an ideal query in terms of efficiency:

- the expected index was used (`cursor` value)
- 1 index entry had to be scanned (`nscanned` value) in order to return 1 result (`n` value)
- the order of documents in the index already satisfied the sort order (`scanAndOrder` value)

#### Why us the aggregation command failing?

> Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.

The exception you are encountering is because your aggregation pipeline doesn't have a suitable index to use and is instead doing an in-memory sort. MongoDB 2.6 has a [100MB memory limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions) for an in-memory sort.

There is an `allowDiskUse` option if you want your aggregation pipeline to use an external sort for a large data set, but in this case the exception is a hint that your pipeline is processing far more data than needed for a single result.

Comment: I can see I failed to explain myself properly. I think the query I was trying to execute might illustrate what I mean. The documents represent information for pairs of IDs, but I'm trying to efficiently query for the "most current" document for *one* of the IDs.

A find(...).sort(...).limit(1) will give me exactly one document, but if I'm querying by regionID, I want one *per* typeID.

Comment: Apologies, I managed to skip over the "pairs" context .. in that case, I have a few more questions :)